# Which Android spin-off can I use for the possible maximum privacy?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lineageos

Complete `mobile phone privacy` is a near impossible feat, but I would like to have as much privacy as one can have.
Which `smartphone OS or version` can get me close enough, while allowing for `dependable functionality`?

Comment: You can check out [GrapheneOS](https://grapheneos.org) (successor of Copperhead OS). However it does not support a lot of devices.

Comment: Thanks, going to check it out.

Comment: samsung knox is a good mainstream alternative